# How to change color of header on every click?

Tags: javascript

Below is the html code,

```
<body onload="alert('Hello')">
    <h1>click here</h1>
</body>
```

below is the javascript code,

```
function init(){
    var h1Tags = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    h1Tags[0].onclick = changeColor;
}

function changeColor(){
    this.innerHTML = "Click Again"

    /*en.wikipsedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A_F */
    var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

    this.style.color = randomColor;
}

document[onload] = init;
```

Above code is suppose to change the color of the header.

What is the problem in this code?

Comment: Look at your console.

Comment: You need the parenthesis when you call your function: `document[onload] = init();`

Comment: _What is the problem in this code?_ Likely in this line `document[onload] = init`. `onload` in this case refers to undefined **variable**. You have to replace it with: `document['onload'] = init` or `document.onload = init`

Comment: _What is the difference between window.onload and document.onload?_ AFAIK both are the same. See [1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document), [2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window)

Comment: @hindmost [code](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/tree/master/html5) does not work as expected after your suggested changes.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is likely in this line:

```
document[onload] = init
```

`onload` in this case refers to (undefined) **variable** which value is used as a property key. So it will be actually evaluated as:

```
document[undefined] = init
```

You have to replace it with either:

```
document['onload'] = init
```

or

```
document.onload = init
```

Comment: I think it is `document['onload'] = init()`, because this [code](http://jsfiddle.net/hfzez9ox/2/) does not work.

Comment: @overexchange No, `document.onload` is expected to be a `function` (callback), not _returning value_ as in your case

Comment: The code works. Your jsFiddle settings mislead you. Your code will only run after `window.onload` (setting to the top left)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I did not get you, when you say, *`window.onload`(setting to the top left)*. we are using `document.onload`

Answer (score -2):

I would suggest you use `window.onload` instead, per [window.onload vs document.onload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588040/window-onload-vs-document-onload).

```js
function init(){
    var h1Tags = document.getElementsByTagName("h1");
    h1Tags[0].onclick = changeColor;
}

function changeColor(){
    this.innerHTML = "Click Again"

    /*en.wikipsedia.org/wiki/List_of_colors:_A_F */
    var randomColor = '#' + Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);

    this.style.color = randomColor;
}

// The line below was your problem
window.onload = init;
```

```css
/* This may be helpful for you */
h1 {
    -webkit-user-select: none; /* webkit (safari, chrome) browsers */
    -moz-user-select: none; /* mozilla browsers */
    -khtml-user-select: none; /* webkit (konqueror) browsers */
    -ms-user-select: none; /* IE10+ */
}
```

```html
<h1>Click here</h1>
```

Notice also the CSS I added so that if people click quickly they don't select the text at the same time.

Comment: Just changed the last line

Comment: But we dont want the return value of `init`, we want to assign a callback

Comment: It works with `window.onload = init` - see updated answer

Comment: This [code](https://github.com/shamhub/FrontEndDev/tree/master/html5) does not work